# Input byte array must be in range 0 < M <= 32 and length must match type-web3j

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp, web3j, java

I have created an api to addCandidates. But when i run the api i get error:

```
Input byte array must be in range 0 < M <= 32 and length must match type
```

My codesnippet for addCandidates is:

```
 @RequestMapping("/addCandidate")
    public String addCandidateDetails(@RequestParam("candidateName") String candidateName, @RequestParam("elecName") String elecName) {
        try{

        String contractAddress = contract.getContractAddress();
        System.out.println(contractAddress);
        contract.addCandidate(candidateName.getBytes(), elecName.getBytes());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            String error = e.getMessage();
            return error;
        }
        return "Success";
    }
```

Code for contract in java is:

```
public RemoteCall<TransactionReceipt> addCandidate(byte[] candidateName, byte[] election) {
    final Function function = new Function(
            FUNC_ADDCANDIDATE, 
            Arrays.<Type>asList(new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.generated.Bytes32(candidateName), 
            new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.generated.Bytes32(election)), 
            Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());
    return executeRemoteCallTransaction(function);
}
```

Can any one tell me what I am doing wrong here?? Is getBytes() the right way to convert string to bytearray??
Any leads would be appreciated. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:
I implemented the following function in my solidity contract:

```
function stringToBytes32(string memory source) public returns (bytes32 result) {
    bytes memory tempEmptyStringTest = bytes(source);
    if (tempEmptyStringTest.length == 0) {
        return 0x0;
    }

    assembly {
        result := mload(add(source, 32))
    }
}
```

Used it in function:

```
  function addCandidate(string candidateName, string election) public {
    bytes32 c1 = stringToBytes32(candidateName);
    bytes32 e1 = stringToBytes32(election);

      candidates[c1] = candidate(c1,e1,0);

    }
```

Comment: That solution will trunc strings larger than 32 bytes, also it might have problems with strings shorter than 31 bytes if they are compressed.